# Existence of continuous sections of a continuous open surjection.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, multivalued-functions, open-map

Let $f : X \to Y$ be a continuous open surjection between Hausdorff spaces.
Does there always exists a continuous section $s: Y \to X$ of $f$? 
If not, under what conditions does one exist?

For the problem I'm considering I have a few additional assuptions available, but they may be red herrings:

- $X$ and $Y$ are compact/locally compact, and
- $\sup_{x \in X} \# f^{-1}(x)<\infty$.

Comment: Generally the answer is no; consider any nontrivial covering map of Hausdorff spaces, e.g. the double cover $S^1 \to S^1$. See also https://qchu.wordpress.com/2014/11/29/topological-diophantine-equations/ for some discussion.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks for that example. I think what I actually want is the existence of local sections. Do you know if anything prevents that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the map $f(z)=z^2$ of the complex plane and try to construct a local section near zero.