Does a continuous surjective map on topological spaces always have a continuous right-inverse?
Suppose I have a continuous surjective map $f:X\to Y$, Then there is a the obvious map $f^{-1}:Y\to P(X)$. Clearly I can use the axiom of choice to get a right-inverse $g$ from this. But is it always possible to choose a continuous right-inverse?
If not, what are some extra assumptions I can make on $f$ so that I can get a continuous right-inverse?

No: consider the double cover of the circle.

Related questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2353029/existence-of-continuous-sections-of-a-continuous-open-surjection, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/224210/existence-of-a-continuous-section

Even a continuous bijective map need not have a continuous right inverse.  For example $$f\colon [0,1) \cup [2,3] \to [0,2]$$ given by $$f(x)=x, \quad {\rm for} \quad x\in [0,1)\quad {\rm and}\quad f(x)=x-1\quad {\rm for} \quad x\in [2,3].$$

@tkf, Wow ok. I assume that it DOES hold if the domain is connected?

No; another classic example is the map $[0, 1) \to S^1$ given by $\theta \mapsto e^{i2\pi \theta}$.

In general, if $\tau$ is a topology on $X$ and $\tau'\subsetneq \tau$ is another topology on $X$, then the identity map $(X,\tau)\to (X,\tau')$ is a continuous bijection, with no right inverse.  In the above example (provided by @NaimFavier), if $\tau$ is the usual topology on $[0,1)$, then we obtain $\tau'$ from $\tau$ by removing all neighbourhoods of $0$, that do not contain $(a,1)$ for some $a\in [0,1)$.  The result is $S^1$.

This is very, very far from true, for quite interesting reasons. Here are some suggestive examples.

Let $f : Y \to X$ be a covering map between reasonable path-connected spaces, classified by a subgroup inclusion $\pi_1(Y) \hookrightarrow \pi_1(X)$. Then $f$ does not admit a continuous section unless $Y = X$ is the trivial cover (equivalently, unless $\pi_1(Y) = \pi_1(X)$). A fundamental example is the complex exponential map $\exp : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}^{\times}$, which is the universal cover of $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$ and hence which does not admit a continuous section; this says exactly that there is no continuous logarithm on $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$.

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, and consider the tangent bundle $T(M)$ of $M$ with the zero section removed; this is a fiber bundle $E \to M$ whose fiber over a point $m \in M$ is the set of nonzero vectors in the tangent space $T_m(M)$, so a continuous section of this map is a continuous non-vanishing vector field on $M$. There are topological obstructions to the existence of such a vector field; famously the hairy ball theorem asserts that $M = S^2$ does not admit such a vector field, and more generally the Poincaré–Hopf theorem implies that if $M$ is closed and admits such a vector field then $\chi(M) = 0$. (There might be slight subtleties here about the difference between continuous and smooth vector fields but I don't think it matters too much.)

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold again, and now construct from the tangent bundle the fiber bundle $E \to M$ whose fibers over a point $m \in M$ is the set of $k$-tuples of linearly independent vectors in the tangent space $T_m(M)$ (essentially a Stiefel manifold). Then a continuous section of this map is a $k$-tuple of linearly independent vector fields on $M$. Again there are topological obstructions to the existence of such vector fields, and the question of exactly how large $k$ can be is highly nontrivial even for the spheres $M = S^n$; see vector fields on spheres for details.


Many variations on this idea are possible using associated bundles. There's an interesting formal analogy between finding continuous sections of a continuous map and finding solutions to Diophantine equations which I discussed at some length here; that post has more examples like the above.
Generally speaking it's easy to write down necessary conditions for the existence of a section but hard to write down sufficient conditions. Necessary conditions can be obtained from any functor on topological spaces: if $f : X \to Y$ is a continuous map with a continuous section then the same must be true of $F(f) : F(X) \to F(Y)$ where $F$ is any functor whatsoever. So, for example, a necessary condition is that $f$ must induce a surjection on homotopy groups, on homology groups, an injection on cohomology groups, that sort of thing.
